# Error in javascript after load it with jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

in my a.html i write this:

```
<script>
function Flike()
{ jQuery('#ft').load('like.php'); }
</script>
```

in the body of a.html i write

```
window.onload = Flike()
```

like.php is:

```
echo " <script> var e = document.createElement('script');
e.async = true;
e.src = '/facebook/like.js';
document.getElementById('ft').appendChild(e);
</script>
";}
```

Still now, All fine and works.

the problem is in like.js
the script isn't work. 
this is like.js

I also tried without the document ready function... didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

window.onload = Flike() is wrong

It should be

```
window.onload = Flike;
```

but if you are using jQuery, why are you not adding it

```
$(window).load(Flike)
```

And if you are just loading a script, why are you not using

```
$.getScript("/facebook/like.js");
```

Finally, if you are calling this after the page load, the document.ready event will not fire again for this new script.

Comment: in the php there is if else...
$.getScript("/facebook/like.js");

is in php echo..
now the script load but break the page

Comment: breaks the page how? Lack of details = no help.

Comment: The problem is in like.js file. if i use simple javascript like hello world it works, but when i use like.js the is a problem.